# Combine two functions whilst they operate separately

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to combine the below two functions whilst keeping them separate?

The `cloneMe` function clones a group of fields and give them new names and ids so using a foreach I can have each group put into the db as a separate row.

The `addRow` function adds 2 fields ('Bracing' and 'Qty') to a cloned group, there can be an unlimited amount of these fields added, but they need to be seen as part of the cloned group made by `cloneMe` so I can put these 2 fields into their own separate db table.

So far everything I have tried to get the `addRow`'s generated fields to be seen as part of the `cloneMe` groups has resulted in the `addRow` fields being seen as empty and only the very 1st one being part of the first group and unable to add anything to the second or beyond groups.

I've put everything into a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AnJzU/ though `addRow` seem to not want to work on there.

`cloneMe` function;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newNum = 2;
    cloneMe = function(el) {
        var newElem = el.clone().attr('id', 'container' + newNum);
        newElem.html(newElem.html().replace(/form\[1\]/g, 'form['+newNum+']'));
        newElem.html(newElem.html().replace(/id="(.*?)"/g, 'id="1'+newNum+'"'));
        $('#cloneb').before(newElem);
        newElem.find('.delete_name').html('<p class="rem_field"><a href="#"><span>X</span></a></p>');
        newNum++;
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.rem_field', function() {
        $(this).closest('.instance').remove();
        return false;
    });    

});
```

`addRow` function;

```
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
   rowNum ++;
   var row = '<span id="rowNum'+rowNum+'"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><label for="test">Bracing:</label><input type="text" name="form['+rowNum+'][brac]['+rowNum+'][bracing]" size="4" class="brac" value=""></td><td><label for="test2">Qty:</label><input type="text" name="form['+rowNum+'][brac]['+rowNum+'][qty]" class="qty" value=""></td><td><input type="button" class="rem" value="X" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></td></tr></table></span>';
   jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
  jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cloneMe code is always cloning the hidden form template with the id "container1". If you want it to clone a form after you have added the extra bracing and quantity rows you will need to pass the proper element to the cloneMe function. Since the first container has an id of "container" and not "container1" your cloneMe call would need to be:

```
cloneMe($('#container'))
```

Of course, that isn't dynamic. That will always clone the top container. If you want to clone the latest container in the list, which is what it seems like you intend, you'll need your "More Details" button to be more dynamic with something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="cloneb" value="More Details" onclick="cloneMe($('#container' + (newNum - 1)));" />
```

This will always clone the number just before your current newNum variable. You should probably do away with your "container1" hidden template and just call your first container "container1". Otherwise that onclick change will not work since it will still clone your hidden container and not the first container where you added new rows.

Comment: Sorry I think you've miss understood a little, I want the cloneMe function to clone container one as it currently is, I mealy want the addRow function to add to the cloned group as if they were part of it. Heres a live version of what I mean, you will notice the problem I'm having also http://elcu.info/system/